# How to solve "AttributeError: 'QPDFDocument' object has no attribute 'initialize' " in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have got the following error when I'm trying to execute example in pdfquery.
  File "C:\workspace-php\test\pdfminer\pdfqueries\pdfquery.py", line 187, in **init**
    doc.initialize()
AttributeError: 'QPDFDocument' object has no attribute 'initialize'

I'm trying to solve this but still i dont get any solution for that.it would be appreciated if some one can help me to solve this.

```
class PDFQuery(object):
    def __init__(self, file,
                    merge_tags=('LTChar', 'LTAnno'),
                    round_floats=True,
                    round_digits=3,
                    input_text_formatter=None,
                    normalize_spaces=True,
                    resort=True,
                    parse_tree_cacher=None,
                    ):
        # store input
        self.merge_tags = merge_tags
        self.round_floats = round_floats
        self.round_digits = round_digits
        self.resort = resort

        # set up input text formatting function, if any
        if input_text_formatter:
            self.input_text_formatter = input_text_formatter
        elif normalize_spaces:
            r = re.compile(r'\s+')
            self.input_text_formatter = lambda s: re.sub(r, ' ', s)
        else:
            self.input_text_formatter = None

        # open doc
        if not hasattr(file, 'read'):
            try:
                file = open(file, 'rb')
            except TypeError:
                raise TypeError("File must be file object or filepath string.")

        parser = PDFParser(file)
        if hasattr(QPDFDocument, 'set_parser'):
            # pdfminer < 20131022
            doc = QPDFDocument()
            parser.set_document(doc)
            doc.set_parser(parser)
        else:
            # pdfminer >= 20131022
            doc = QPDFDocument(parser)
            parser.set_document(doc)
        doc.initialize()
        self.doc = doc
        self.parser = parser
        self.tree = None
        self.pq = None
        self.file = file

        if parse_tree_cacher:
            self._parse_tree_cacher = parse_tree_cacher
            self._parse_tree_cacher.set_hash_key(self.file)
        else:
            self._parse_tree_cacher = DummyCache()

        # set up layout parsing
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        laparams = LAParams(all_texts=True, detect_vertical=True)
        self.device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
        self.interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, self.device)

        # caches
        self._pages = []
        self._pages_iter = None
        self._elements = []

    def load(self, *page_numbers):
        """
            Load etree and pyquery object for entire document, or given page numbers (ints or lists).
            After this is called, objects are available at pdf.tree and pdf.pq.

            >>> pdf.load()
            >>> pdf.tree
            <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at ...>
            >>> pdf.pq('LTPage')
            [<LTPage>, <LTPage>]
            >>> pdf.load(1)
            >>> pdf.pq('LTPage')
            [<LTPage>]
            >>> pdf.load(0,1)
            >>> pdf.pq('LTPage')
            [<LTPage>, <LTPage>]
        """
        self.tree = self.get_tree(*_flatten(page_numbers))
        self.pq = self.get_pyquery(self.tree)

    def extract(self, searches, tree=None, as_dict=True):
        """
            >>> foo = pdf.extract( [ ['pages', 'LTPage'] ])
            >>> foo
            {'pages': [<LTPage>, <LTPage>]}
            >>> pdf.extract( [ ['bar', ':in_bbox("100,100,400,400")'] ], foo['pages'][0])
            {'bar': [<LTTextLineHorizontal>, <LTTextBoxHorizontal>,...
        """
        if self.tree is None or self.pq is None:
            self.load()
        pq = PyQuery(tree, css_translator=PDFQueryTranslator()) if tree is not None else self.pq
        if tree is None:
            pq = self.pq
        else:
            pq = PyQuery(tree, css_translator=PDFQueryTranslator())
        results = []
        formatter = None
        parent = pq
        for search in searches:
            if len(search) < 3:
                search = list(search) + [formatter]
            key, search, tmp_formatter = search
            if key == 'with_formatter':
                if isinstance(search, basestring): # is a pyquery method name, e.g. 'text'
                    formatter = lambda o, search=search: getattr(o, search)()
                elif hasattr(search, '__call__') or not search: # is a method, or None to end formatting
                    formatter = search
                else:
                    raise TypeError("Formatter should be either a pyquery method name or a callable function.")
            elif key == 'with_parent':
                parent = pq(search) if search else pq
            else:
                try:
                    result = parent("*").filter(search) if hasattr(search, '__call__') else parent(search)
                except cssselect.SelectorSyntaxError, e:
                    raise cssselect.SelectorSyntaxError( "Error applying selector '%s': %s" % (search, e) )
                if tmp_formatter:
                    result = tmp_formatter(result)
                results += result if type(result) == tuple else [[key, result]]
        if as_dict:
            results = dict(results)
        return results





    # tree building stuff

    def get_pyquery(self, tree=None, page_numbers=[]):
        """
            Wrap given tree in pyquery and return.
            If no tree supplied, will generate one from given page_numbers, or all page numbers.
        """
        if tree is None:
            if not page_numbers and self.tree is not None:
                tree = self.tree
            else:
                tree = self.get_tree(page_numbers)
        if hasattr(tree, 'getroot'):
            tree = tree.getroot()
        return PyQuery(tree, css_translator=PDFQueryTranslator())

    def get_tree(self, *page_numbers):
        """
            Return lxml.etree.ElementTree for entire document, or page numbers given if any.
        """
        cache_key = "_".join(map(str, _flatten(page_numbers)))
        tree = self._parse_tree_cacher.get(cache_key)
        if tree is None:
            # set up root
            root = parser.makeelement("pdfxml")
            if self.doc.info:                           #not all PDFs seem to have this info section
                for k, v in self.doc.info[0].items():
                    root.set(k, unicode(v))
            # add pages
            if page_numbers:
                pages = [[n, self.get_layout(self.get_page(n))] for n in _flatten(page_numbers)]
            else:
                pages = enumerate(self.get_layouts())
            for n, page in pages:
                page = self._xmlize(page)
                page.set('page_index', unicode(n))
                page.set('page_label', self.doc.get_page_number(n))
                root.append(page)
            self._clean_text(root)
            # wrap root in ElementTree
            tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
            self._parse_tree_cacher.set(cache_key, tree)
        return tree

    def _clean_text(self, branch):
        """
            Remove text from node if same text exists in its children.
            Apply string formatter if set.
        """
        if branch.text and self.input_text_formatter:
            branch.text = self.input_text_formatter(branch.text)
        try:
            for child in branch:
                self._clean_text(child)
                if branch.text and branch.text.find(child.text) >= 0:
                    branch.text = branch.text.replace(child.text, '', 1)
        except TypeError: # not an iterable node
            pass


    def _xmlize(self, node, root=None):

        # collect attributes of current node
        tags = self._getattrs(node, 'y0', 'y1', 'x0', 'x1', 'width', 'height', 'bbox', 'linewidth', 'pts', 'index','name','matrix','word_margin' )
        if type(node) == LTImage:
            tags.update( self._getattrs(node, 'colorspace','bits','imagemask','srcsize','stream','name','pts','linewidth') )
        elif type(node) == LTChar:
            tags.update( self._getattrs(node, 'fontname','adv','upright','size') )
        elif type(node) == LTPage:
            tags.update( self._getattrs(node, 'pageid','rotate') )

        # create node
        branch = parser.makeelement(node.__class__.__name__, tags)
        branch.layout = node
        self._elements += [branch] # make sure layout keeps state
        if root is None:
            root = branch

        # add text
        if hasattr(node, 'get_text'):
            branch.text = node.get_text()

        # add children if node is an iterable
        if hasattr(node, '__iter__'):
            last = None
            for child in node:
                child = self._xmlize(child, root)
                if self.merge_tags and child.tag in self.merge_tags:
                    if branch.text and child.text in branch.text:
                        continue
                    elif last is not None and last.tag in self.merge_tags:
                        last.text += child.text
                        last.set('_obj_id', last.get('_obj_id')+","+child.get('_obj_id'))
                        continue
                # sort children by bounding boxes
                if self.resort:
                    _append_sorted(root, child, _comp_bbox)
                else:
                    branch.append(child)
                last = child

        return branch

    def _getattrs(self, obj, *attrs):
        """ Return dictionary of given attrs on given object, if they exist, processing through filter_value(). """
        return dict( (attr, unicode(self._filter_value(getattr(obj, attr)))) for attr in attrs if hasattr(obj, attr))

    def _filter_value(self, val):
        if self.round_floats:
            if type(val) == float:
                val = round(val, self.round_digits)
            elif hasattr(val, '__iter__'):
                val = [self._filter_value(item) for item in val]
        return val



    # page access stuff

    def get_page(self, page_number):
        """ Get PDFPage object -- 0-indexed."""
        return self._cached_pages(target_page=page_number)

    def get_layout(self, page):
        """ Get PDFMiner Layout object for given page object or page number. """
        if type(page) == int:
            page = self.get_page(page)
        self.interpreter.process_page(page)
        return self.device.get_result()

    def get_layouts(self):
        """ Get list of PDFMiner Layout objects for each page. """
        return (self.get_layout(page) for page in self._cached_pages())

    def _cached_pages(self, target_page=-1):
        """
            Get a page or all pages from page generator, caching results.
            This is necessary because PDFMiner searches recursively for pages,
            so we won't know how many there are until we parse the whole document,
            which we don't want to do until we need to.
        """
        try:
            # pdfminer < 20131022
            self._pages_iter = self._pages_iter or self.doc.get_pages()
        except AttributeError:
            # pdfminer >= 20131022
            self._pages_iter = self._pages_iter or PDFPage.create_pages(self.doc)

        if target_page >= 0:
            while len(self._pages) <= target_page:
                next = self._pages_iter.next()
                if not next:
                    return None
                next.page_number = 0
                self._pages += [next]
            try:
                return self._pages[target_page]
            except IndexError:
                return None
        self._pages += list(self._pages_iter)
        return self._pages


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    pdf = PDFQuery("../examples/sample.pdf")
    doctest.testmod(extraglobs={'pdf': pdf}, optionflags=doctest.ELLIPSIS)
```

Answer (score 0):

add.elif to line 18 then add a for loop before the list and that should fix it if there is any problems contact me for support